# How to add condition with calling model/table from caller model with laravel eloquent relationship method for dynamic searching?

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to collect related data of customers from three table view them as one table on browser, and to search dynamically with the value of severate columns from three tables.

Here is the code:

```
public function customersList(Request $request)
    {
        $info = [];
        $data = [];

        // if (!empty($request->value)) :
        //     $info = DB::table('customers')
        //         ->join('phones', 'customers.id', '=', 'phones.customer_id',)
        //         ->join('emails', 'customers.id', '=', 'emails.customer_id',)
        //         ->select('customers.id', 'customers.name', 'emails.email', 'emails.customer_id', 'phones.phone', 'phones.customer_id')
        //         ->where('customers.name', 'like', '%' . $request->value . '%')
        //         ->orWhere('emails.email', 'like', '%' . $request->value . '%')
        //         ->orWhere('phones.phone', 'like', '%' . $request->value . '%')
        //         ->get();
        // else :
        //     $info = DB::table('customers')
        //         ->join('phones', 'customers.id', '=', 'phones.customer_id',)
        //         ->join('emails', 'customers.id', '=', 'emails.customer_id',)
        //         ->select('customers.id', 'customers.name', 'emails.email', 'emails.customer_id', 'phones.phone', 'phones.customer_id')
        //         ->get();
        // endif;

        // $i = 0;
        // foreach ($info as $item) :
        //     $item = (array)$item;
        //     if (isset($data[$i]['id']) && $data[$i]['id'] != $item['id']) :
        //         $data[$i]['id'] = $item['id'];
        //         $data[$i]['name'] = $item['name'];
        //     endif;
        //     $i++;
        // endforeach;

        if (!empty($request->value)) :
            $customers = Customer::where('name', 'like', '%' . $request->value . '%')->get();
        else :
            $customers = Customer::all();
        endif;


        foreach ($customers as $customer) :
            if ((!empty($request->all()))) :
                $emails[] = Customer::find($customer['id'])->emails()->where('email', 'like', '%' . $request->value . '%')->get();
            else :
                $emails[] = Customer::find($customer['id'])->emails;
            endif;
            if (!empty($request->all())) :
                $phones[] = Customer::find($customer['id'])->phones()->where('phone', 'like', '%' . $request->value . '%')->get();
            else :
                $phones[] = Customer::find($customer['id'])->phones;
            endif;
        endforeach;

        foreach ($customers as $customer) :
            $data[$customer['id']]['id'] = $customer['id'];
            $data[$customer['id']]['name'] = $customer['name'];
            $data[$customer['id']]['age'] = $customer['age'];
            $data[$customer['id']]['gender'] = $customer['gender'];
            foreach ($emails as $item) :
                $i = 1;
                foreach ($item as $email) :
                    if ($customer['id'] == $email['customer_id']) :
                        $data[$customer['id']]['email-' . $i] = $email['email'];
                    endif;
                    $i++;
                endforeach;
            endforeach;
            foreach ($phones as $item) :
                $i = 1;
                foreach ($item as $phone) :
                    if ($customer['id'] == $phone['customer_id']) :
                        $data[$customer['id']]['phone-' . $i] = $phone['phone'];
                    endif;
                    $i++;
                endforeach;
            endforeach;
        endforeach;

        return response()->json([
            'status' => 200,
            'data' => $data
        ]);
    }
```

Note: Please ignore the comented line. Those are because I tried get output in another way.

The output is:
[image]

But the prolem is when I try to search with customers table data like name, live search is ok and data filters perfectly. But search doesn't work for field like phone from phones, email from emails that is other two tables.

What is wrong in my code? I don't know eloquent relationship.
Can anyone help with my code?

Answer (score 0):

Can you please explain about the structure of the view/tables,
Below mentioned code is with my understanding about the structure

Call the emails and phones as laravel relationship if those are in different tables,select the relationship type according to your table structure

```
 $customers = Customer::with(['emails','phones']);
    if(!empty($searchKey = $request->value)){
        $customers->where(function(Builder $query)use($searchKey){
            $query->where("name","LIKE","%$searchKey%");
                  ->orWhereHas('emails',fn($query2)=>$query2->where("email","LIKE","%$searchKey%"))
                  ->orWhereHas('phones',fn($query3)=>$query3->where("phone","LIKE","%$searchKey%"));
        });
    }
```

Fetching and formatting the response

```
    $customers = $customers->get()->map(function($customer){
        $data[$customer['id']] = [
                                    'id'=>$customer['id'],
                                    'name'=>$customer['name'],
                                    'age'=>$customer['age'],
                                    'gender'=>$customer['gender'],
                                    'emails'=>collect($customer['emails'])->only('email'),
                                    'phone'=>collect($customer['phones'])->only('phone'),
                                ];

        
        return $data;
    });
```

Returning the response

```
return response()->json(['status' => 200,'data' => $data]);
```

Comment: I understood nothiing. But, thaank you for your kind cooperation @Jeybin George.

Comment: If you have separate tables/views for the emails and phones add create relationships inside the model. If the search key is not empty first it will search in the name column, then if the emails and phones relationships are not empty, it will search inside the relationships with the column names email,phone respectively.Then at the end it will map the data change the response according to your purpose @Solutions

Comment: Thank you very much for your response, mr. @jeybin George. But I wanted it with query builder, Is it possible to get desired output with query builder.

Comment: I have tried your code @jeybin George. But, It didn't work when I tries to search. and when I active second part . and error occurred that get() function need an argument, that is -       message "Too few arguments to function Illuminate\\Support\\Collection::get(), 0 passed in C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\laravel\\app\\Http\\Controllers\\CustomerController.php on line 59 and at least 1 expected"